# What is the common approach to include pictures/figures from pdf files or other sources?

Tags: graphics, png, jpeg, powerpoint

What is the common approach to include pictures/figures from pdf files or other sources?
My approach is to save the graphic as a jpg. Afterwards I include it into a Power Point and safe it from PP to a png. This is my approach to keep all figures the same size and resolution. Unfortunately, these pictures have a bad resolution.

What is a more elegant and better way to do it?

Comment: It seems to me that this question is off topic on this site.

Comment: Well, I just started to use LaTeX, so maybe it is a trivial question for you, but maybe a very useful for the newbies.

Comment: @Denis Well, it's no really clear what you want. Do you seek for a way to include graphics in LaTeX? Or to extract graphics from other sources? If second, it's offtopic and better for SuperUser.SE.

Comment: I apologize for that. My goal is to find a general approach how to deal with graphics with different resolution so that every figure in my paper looks the same, no matter where it comes from...

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the `\includegraphics` macro, which is part of the `graphicx` package. I suggest reading [this article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics).

Comment: Using eps files instead png files is a good thing, but I can't get eps files from pdf files. I am using figures from papers, which are in pdf files. Using figures from different sources is giving me picures with different resolutions. How can I deal with that? Do I have to pre process the graphic or can I do it with a command.

Comment: @Denis If you compile your LaTeX with pdflatex, then `includegraphics` can include pdf, jpeg, png, ...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments:

- My goal is to find a general approach how to deal with graphics with different resolution so that every figure in my paper looks the same, no matter where it comes from.
- Using EPS files instead PNG files is a good thing, but I can't get EPS files from PDF files. I am using figures from papers, which are in PDF files. Using figures from different sources is giving me pictures with different resolutions. How can I deal with that? Do I have to pre-process the graphic or can I do it with a command.

**My solutions are as follows**:

To make your imported graphics look the same (probably in size), you can use `width` or `height` option of `\includegraphics` macro from `graphicx` package. Put `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble and invoke `\includegraphics[width=10cm]{filename}` or `\includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{filename}` or any other variants.

Comment: Is it also possible to change the resolution somehow?