# How to include a pdf image

Tags: graphics, pdf

All I am trying to include a pdf image in my `tex` file, but when I compiled the `tex` file, the console pop up the following error msg:

> ! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in time_elapsed.pdf (no Boundin
>       gBox).

This is my code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{time_elapsed.pdf}
\label{fig5}
\end{figure}
```

So how to solve the problem?

Comment: Which driver you are using (pdfTeX, LuaTeX, XeTeX, dvips, dvipdfm, ...)?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek:I have updated my post, it is a different error msg now, I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: You're probably using `latex` which only accepts EPS files and not PDF.

Comment: I have used a few eps files as well, so i can't use pdflatex, coz my other eps files wont be compiled

Comment: Just convert the EPS files to PDF. Depending on your TeX distribution, this can even be automatic if you load the `epstopdf` package.

Comment: when i use pdfLatex, I got an error msg: {\cont 
! File ended while scanning use of \@writefile.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.27 \begin{document}
                     
?

Answer (score 4):

Try to compile the following with `pdflatex`. The simplest workflow should be like the following.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}% no need to explicitly specify the file extension.
\end{document}
```

You will get an output as follows.

[image]

### Useful links:

- [How to deal with PDF figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63227/19356)
- [What is the common approach to include pictures/figures from pdf files or other sources?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112344/19356)
- [How to pass a single file path argument to a macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69598/19356)

Comment: If you include the `mwe` package it becomes a MWE.

Comment: @percusse: But it still works without `mwe` package.

Comment: Loading the `mwe` package once, makes the images to stay available even when the package is not loaded.

Comment: @percusse: I am trying to parse your sentence.

Answer (score 3):

> ! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in time_elapsed.pdf
>   (no Boundin gBox).

That looks very much like the error produced by latex when you try to include pure PostScript (.ps) image instead of encapsulated PostScript (.eps). Are you sure you are using pdflatex command for TeX-ing?